# how to set gradle_home in mint

Tags: java, gradle

I installed gradle using apt-get. And when using IDEA to configure gradle, it needs to specify the  gradle home. I specify /usr/share/gradle/ as gradle home, but IDEA complain it is not a correct gradle home. So how should I configure gradle home?

```
 /usr/share/gradle $ ls -l /usr/share/gradle/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 11  8 17:00 lib
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like a Gradle home (not sure if the apt package will give you one). The easiest and best solution is to avoid local Gradle installations altogether, and use the [Gradle Wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) for each build. IDEA will then also use the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

`GRADLE_HOME` should point to the directory which has `bin/gradle` under it; I never had installed gradle using `apt-get`, but I extract the zip. So if for example I extract the zip to `/scratch/skgupta/gradle_2_1/` then I would set this as my `GRADLE_HOME` and make sure `$GRADLE_HOME/bin/gradle` exists.

In your case, you should just run 'which gradle' and set the GRADLE_HOME accordingly.

That said, I agree with @peter to use gradle wrapper and avoid local installation

HTH